# Android ICS SOAP Method Not Working?

Tags: android, soap, xml-parsing

I tested SOAP method in **samsung galaxy tab** and is working fine.

same code i tested on **Android ice cream sandwich** and is not working.

Below is My code,

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("xxxxxx");        
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", SoapAction);

            StringEntity se1 = new StringEntity(env,HTTP.UTF_8);
            se1.setContentType("text/xml");  
            se1.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
            httppost.setEntity(se1);  

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httppost);

            System.out.println("res------"+httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString()+" code  "+httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            //Checking response 
            if(httpResponse!=null){
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();


                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line="";
                try {
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        total.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("line----"+line);            
            }
```

In this code I printed **httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString()** printed value like this
**HTTP/1.1 200 OK code  200**

but line value getting null.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: Before calling the network related functions. Better to use below declaration of main class.